# How to list the size of a directoy and subdirectories and files inside it by terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, directory

Is there a command to **list a directory total size** and then each **sub-folder** and **files** inside it .

I also want to sort them by **increasing order** so that I can see which folder is greater in size.

Answer (score 15):

```
du -sh * | sort -h
```

will get you a human-readable ascending list of the sizes of files and subdirectories in your current directory,

```
du -sh
```

will summarize the current directory size.

Comment: The 1st command will error out if a file starts with a  `-`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is like below :

i used **du** command for that purpose .

```
du : Summarize disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories.
```

As the picture below i want to see the size of a folder name test and recursively the sub folders and each file in kb :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do `ls -sh` to list the file size of the files and folder in the current directory
`ls -shR *` will list the size and name of files recursively